# How to mark a bug as unreproducible?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio Online, how should we mark bugs that are not reproducible? I don't want to mark them as "Done", obviously. Marking them as "Removed" feels weird, but maybe that's the correct way to handle them. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of thing you can solve with tags. You're not fixing the bug -- the reason doesn't matter. It's "Done". Then tag it as "No-Repro", and you have a way to track it.

Answer (score 2):

As Bugs are the result os a failing Test Case you should not have any Bugs that are not reproducible. It's about workflow.

When a user reports issue should a tester to use exploratory trying tools to verify that it is indeed a bug.

At that point they can create both the Bug and related Test Case that proves that it exists.

Ultimately you should never have a bug in your system that does not have a Test Case associated.

If you don't have that workflow then you can use Tags as Daniel suggests, but changing your workflow would be a better option. Less rework...